# How to increase label or text view size (height and width) in tableview by objective c(For Conversation Page) Can you Help me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I can't Increase Label or Textview Size in table view by objective c. 
I'm Struck for this problem.

Comment: put your code or provide some detail information.

Comment: Nanbaa... Show what you've tried so far for better assistance.

Comment: Friend i've tried more code but when i create label programatically It works but when i add more chat that designs will be currupted So i need to implement with uilabel in story board  . thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer with easy method using contraints(set maximum and minimum width and height for label)[Thats the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atvgG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding up my code ..

```
#pragma mark - TABLE VIEW DELEGATE

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChatCell";

    ChatCell *cell = (ChatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ChatCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.txtView.text=[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(indexPath.row%2){
        cell.txtView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.leading.constant=0.0f;
    }else{
        cell.txtView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:246.0f/255 green:190.0f/255 blue:175.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
        cell.leading.constant=((tblView.frame.size.width)/2)-50-16;
    }
    [cell.subView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [cell.subView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
    [cell.subView.layer setShadowRadius:0.0f];
    [cell.subView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 2.0)];
    [cell.txtView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [cell.txtView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];


    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSDictionary *attributesName = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@".SFUIText-Regular" size:14.0f]};


    CGRect r1 = [[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake((tblView.frame.size.width/2)+50, 0)
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:attributesName
                                      context:nil];


    return r1.size.height+70;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [messages count];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}
```

Adding the ChatCell properties list. Cell contains a subView and textview with in subview(top, leading, bottom, trailing of textview all connected to subview) and leading is the auto layout constraint connecting superview and subview leading end.

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextView *txtView;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDate;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *subView;

@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leading;
```

Comment: Thank you friend but i did't know what leading and subview are what type of object So i can't run my project

Comment: Thanks a lot saraswati i've tried more time but i can't get cleared output.Here is my screen shot.https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=794651007338164&set=a.104813199655285.6004.100003798157583&type=3&theater

Answer (score 0):

**If you use textview**

```
-(void)textView
    {
        CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        NSLog(@"this is updating height%@",NSStringFromCGSize(newFrame.size));

               height=newFrame.size.height;


    }
```

Get the height from this method then set it to heightforrow method

Set constraints for the textview leading,trailing,top,bottom.

Comment: machi label size icreament da in table view

Comment: @Subramani use textview and set it as non editable so that it will be easy

Comment: ---->    -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
    {

Comment: ethu ku da table view la text view functiona epdi add panna mudium